# How to transform pandas column of arrays by dropping a value retrieved from the same row

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe with a column `first_name` (string) and another column `name_variations` (array). How can I perform a column operation on the name_variations array so that I can drop any value contained in the array that matches value of first_name field?

For example, here is the initial dataframe:

```
data = {'first_name':  ['Robert',
                    'Richard',
                    'Joseph'],
    'name_variations': [np.array(['Robert', 'Rob', 'Bob']),
                        np.array(['Rich', 'Richard', 'Rick']),
                        np.array(['Joe'])],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['first_name','name_variations'])
```

This gives a dataframe like this:

```
  first_name        name_variations
0     Robert     [Robert, Rob, Bob]
1    Richard  [Rich, Richard, Rick]
2     Joseph                  [Joe]
```

I would like to transform it so that Robert and Richard are dropped from the first two values of name_variation (based on first_name column), but the third value remains the same.

Desired output:

```
  first_name name_variations
0     Robert      [Rob, Bob]
1    Richard    [Rich, Rick]
2     Joseph           [Joe]
```

Editing question after Chris's correct answer to original question. I should have mentioned in my question that my dataframe is rather large (1 million rows) and I want to see if a vectorized operation is possible, rather that using apply, which is slower.

Comment: Nice job with the question. Easy to recreate the dataframe, and clear desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['name_variations'] = df.apply(lambda row: [x for x in row['name_variations'] if x!= row['first_name']], axis=1)
```

Or

```
df = df.explode('name_variations')
df[df['first_name']!=df['name_variations']].groupby('first_name')['name_variations'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Your answer is correct and it worked. I should have mentioned in my question that my dataframe is rather large (1 million rows) and I wanted to see if a vectorized operation was possible, rather that using apply, which is slower.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `explode`:

```
df['name_variations'] = (df.explode('name_variations')
                           .query('first_name != name_variations')
                           .groupby(level=0)['name_variations']
                           .agg(list))
```

Output:

```
  first_name name_variations
0     Robert      [Rob, Bob]
1    Richard    [Rich, Rick]
2     Joseph           [Joe]
```

---

Another way using nested list comprehension

```
df['name_variations'] = [[i for i in x if (i != df['first_name']).all()] for x in df['name_variations']]
```

Timings:

```
%timeit df['name_variations'] = df.explode('name_variations').query('first_name != name_variations').groupby(level=0)['name_variations'].agg(list)
10.1 ms ± 294 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.apply(lambda row: [x for x in row['name_variations'] if x!= row['first_name']], axis=1)
2.33 ms ± 68.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df['name_variations'] = [[i for i in x if (i != df['first_name']).all()] for x in df['name_variations']]
1.67 ms ± 66.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```